# How to make android application consume JAX Jersey Web Service running on tomcat on same machine

Tags: java, android, web-services, client, jax-rs

I'm a newbie that needs some help...

I just managed to run a Java Dynamic Web Application webservice using Jersey + JSON and hitting a mysql db using Android Developer Tools Eclipse... Tomcat7 runs webservice fine for now and can interact with db through browser URLs with parameters...
I also have a running Android application which has data I need to store in the mysql db through the webservice...

I've been searching a lot of tutorials which use several different frameworks with no luck, I'm pretty confused...
I run one eclipse with the android app and the android phone in debug mode connected through USB...
Another eclipse runs the Dynamic Web Application webservice using Jersey and Tomcat7...

How could I make my client android app consume the webservice running on the same development machine?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any number of http/rest client libraries. You can even use standard Java, without any libraries (using the classes in the `java.net` package)

Sample using `java.net` package classes

```
URL url = new URL("http://blah.com/messages/1");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new BetterLuckNextTimeException(...);
}

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())
);
// read
connection.disconnect();
```

Then there's the very popular [Apache HttpClient Library](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). Check out the quick start and tutorials from the link. The download also comes with a good user guide in pdf.

Some Sample

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://blah.com/messages/1");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
try {
    System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
    HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
    // do something useful with the response body
    // and ensure it is fully consumed
    EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
} finally {
    response.close();
}
```

Then of course there's the JAX-RX implementation's client library. From [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368229/how-to-make-web-page-access-mysql-db-through-already-running-jax-ws-webservice-i) looks like you're using Jersey. Since you haven't explained which version, I'll just point you in the direction where you can find more information, along with code snippets.

- [Jersey 2.13 Client API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) - The client API comes with the Jersey Distribution, which you *should* have if you are using Jersey on the backend.
- [Jersey 1.18 Client API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#client-api) - Same deal should be included.

---

If you try using any of these, and you are running into trouble, please post a complete example that demonstrates the problem. Including 1) A sample backend resource class. 2) The client code 3) Any related error/exception messages 4) All the jar archives you have included (if necessary)